# Converting the left over decminal to weeks, days, hours, min, seconds

Tags: java, math, plugins, minecraft

Right now I am finding out 25% of a persons years and for example if you had 5 years 25% is 1.25. Though the plugin im making cant remove 1.25 years from you the .25 needs to be converted to weeks and then any leftovers to days and so on. Though I dont know how I would convert these times.

```
Integer y = itapi.getPlayerYears(player.getName());
Double yremove = Integer.valueOf(y) * 0.25;
Integer w = itapi.getPlayerWeeks(player.getName());
Double wremove = Integer.valueOf(w) * 0.25;
Integer d = itapi.getPlayerDays(player.getName());
Double dremove = Integer.valueOf(d) * 0.25;
Integer h = itapi.getPlayerHours(player.getName());
Double hremove = Integer.valueOf(h) * 0.25;
Integer m = itapi.getPlayerMinutes(player.getName());
Double mremove = Integer.valueOf(m) * 0.25;
Integer s = itapi.getPlayerSeconds(player.getName());
Double sremove = Integer.valueOf(s) * 0.25;
String yminus = String.valueOf(yremove) + 'y';
String wminus = String.valueOf(wremove) + 'w';
String dminus = String.valueOf(dremove) + 'd';
String hminus = String.valueOf(hremove) + 'h';
String mminus = String.valueOf(mremove) + 'm';
String sminus = String.valueOf(sremove) + 's';
ItemStack book = itapi.createTimeCard("Death of " + player.getName(), yminus + wminus + dminus + hminus + mminus + sminus, 1);
itapi.removeTime(player.getName(), yminus + wminus + dminus + hminus + mminus + sminus );
e.getDrops().add(book);
```

Would it be possible to work the conversion out or would it be better to convert all time to seconds then take 25% and convert it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use nested ifs and pass the remainder around. I have not tested this but it should give you an idea.

```
Integer y = itapi.getPlayerYears(player.getName());
double yremove = Integer.valueOf(y) *0.25;
double numWeeks = yremove * 52; //returns the number in weeks
double numDays =0;
double numHours =0;
double numMinutes =0;
double numSeconds =0;
if(numWeeks % 52 != 0){
    numDays = (numWeeks % 52) * 7;
    if(numDays % 7 !=0){
          numHours = (numDays % 7) * 24;
          if(numHours % 24 !=0){
              numMinutes = (numHours % 24) * 60;
              if(numMinutes % 60 !=0){
                   numSeconds = (numMinutes % 60) * 60;
              }
          }
    }
}
//... then convert to string as you are already doing and pass it to removeTime()
```

Comment: `int numWeeks = yremove * 52;` Throws: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int`

Comment: Yes. You should declare them as double instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Calendar` class to calculate this for you, something like:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    double millis = 1.25 * 31557600 * 1000;
    long l = (long) millis;
    c.setTimeInMillis(l);

    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "  Year");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " months");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) + " weeks");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " days");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + " hours");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes");
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + " seconds");
```

**Output:**
    1971 Year
    3 months
    1 weeks
    2 days
    7 hours
    0 minutes
    0 seconds

Calendar defaults the starting year to 1970, you can further manipulate year and months to weeks if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to manage time.  This class will have methods to return time in terms of years, weeks, months, etc.

```
public class Time{
    private long milliseconds;

    public double getSeconds(){
        double seconds = milliseconds/1000.0;
        return seconds;
    }
    public void subtractSeconds(double seconds){
        long millisInSeconds = (long)(seconds*1000);
        this.millisecionds -= millisInSeconds;
    }
    //write more methods for years, months etc.
}
```

Then, use this class to retrieve years, months, weeks and subtract the difference.  This will keep your code clean, and easy to understand.

```
Time time = new Time(1000*60*60);
int years = (int)time.getYears();
time.subtractYears(years);
int months = (int)time.getMonths();
time.subtractMonths(months);
```